# How to encode and decode NSString in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, ios7

I am developing an app which should support iOS5,iOS6,iOS7.

In my app i want to encode my `NSString` Data using `base64encoding`.

Following is the code I am using for encoding

```
NSString *userData = @"data";
NSString *base64EncodedString = [[userData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

The above code is running fine in iOS7, but in iOS6 the application crashes,with the following error:

```
[NSConcreteMutableData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:]
```

Is there any other way to encode data Or any function which support iOS6 & iOS7.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does the Xcode documentation say about the availability of base64EncodedStringWithOptions?

Comment: You need to find (or write) another base64 encoding algorithm since the one you are using is only for iOS 7 or later.

Comment: See initWithBase64Encoding .

Comment: Oh, okay...  Sorry about that.  The Xcode documentation says 'Available in OS X v10.6 and later,' though.

Comment: @ElTomato Are you looking at the Mac documentation?

Comment: It's Xcode.  It says "Although this method was only introduced publicly for iOS 7, it has existed since iOS 4; you can use it if your application needs to target an operating system prior to iOS 7. This method behaves like initWithBase64EncodedString:options:, but ignores all unknown characters."  I never use base64Encoding.  So I'm sure you guys know more about this stuff.  See under Deprecated in OS X v10.9.

Comment: possible duplicate of [-\[NSConcreteMutableData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x776e920'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254982/nsconcretemutabledata-base64encodedstringwithoptions-unrecognized-selector)

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment for some reason, so I'll link to an [old StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844018/1349663) that provides a plausible solution. Basically, you convert the NSString to NSData and encode the NSData.

```
+ (NSString *)toBase64String:(NSString *)string {
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
    NSString *ret = [NSStringUtil base64StringFromData:data length:[data length]];
    return ret;
}
```

Of course, you could check for iOS7 and use `initWithBase64EncodedString:options:` for that case.